# scripts not executing in jenkins in docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am setting up docker for jenkins and installing plugins in it.For this execution there are few lines as below in Dockerfile:

```
COPY plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
# Adding required plugins
COPY plugins.txt /plugins.txt
RUN cd /usr/local/bin && ls -al && echo 'Hello'
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /plugins.txt
```

it is giving output as:

```
Step 64/73 : RUN cd /usr/local/bin && ls -al && echo 'Hello'
 ---> Running in 99b837dbd42c
total 53068
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Jun 14 12:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Jan  9 19:37 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       87 Jun  6 01:55 docker-java-home
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     5000 Jun 11 07:00 jenkins-support
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     1301 Jun 11 07:00 jenkins.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54308597 Jun  6 10:56 kubectl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     3917 Jun 11 07:00 plugins.sh
Hello
Removing intermediate container 99b837dbd42c
 ---> bfa6a11b18da
Step 65/73 : RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /plugins.txt
 ---> Running in fd2f5cf8de36
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh: Permission denied
```

It is evident that permission is not there for executing the script so,I have added this too in second line:

```
COPY plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh 
# Adding required plugins
COPY plugins.txt /plugins.txt
RUN cd /usr/local/bin && ls -al && echo 'Hello'
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /plugins.txt
```

It is again giving me error as:

```
Step 63/74 : RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
 ---> Running in 375d0c56e9c3
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/bin/plugins.sh': Operation not permitted
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: try to run ```chmod +x``` directly, not in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

It was a minor mistake but it gives an important lesson:

**While executing Dockerfile, for all the files we are copying from local to the docker container,there permission will always remain as it is and cannot be changed.**

Permissions on Host machine:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 sevenos sevenos 1301 Jun 11 12:30 jenkins.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 sevenos sevenos 3917 Jun 11 12:30 plugins.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 sevenos sevenos  806 Jun 11 12:30 plugins.txt
```

Permissions in Docker:

```
Step 64/73 : RUN cd /usr/local/bin && ls -al && echo 'Hi'
 ---> Running in 71c1dff30ffc
total 53068
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Jun 14 12:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Jan  9 19:37 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       87 Jun  6 01:55 docker-java-home
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     5000 Jun 11 07:00 jenkins-support
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     1301 Jun 11 07:00 jenkins.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54308597 Jun  6 10:56 kubectl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     3917 Jun 11 07:00 plugins.sh
```